# dual of continuous fuctions with support compact

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let X be a locally compact Hausdorff space and $C_{b}$(X) the set of all continuous functions with support compact. The dual of $C_{b}$ is isometric isomorphism of M(X), with M(X) the set of all regular Borel measures on X? Do the measures need to be finite as well?

Comment: $C_b(X)$ are continuous bounded functions on $X$. You probably mean $C_c(X)$. In that case, $C_c(X)^* = C_0(X)^* = M(X)$.

Comment: do you know where that proof is? @QuantumSpace

Comment: It is in chapter 7 of Folland's book on real analysis, in Rudin's second book and in many other places

Comment: QuantumSpace's comment refers to the dual of $C_c$ with respect to the norm topology, while the answer refers to the dual of $C_c$ with respect to the inductive topology. You should clarify which one you mean. @AnabelPérez

Answer (score 1):

No, the measures in the dual space of $C_c(X)$ are not necessarily finite. Think of $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$. Then
$$ \lambda(f) = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x) \ \mathrm{d} \lambda(x) $$
defines a functional on $C_c(\mathbb{R})$, the space of continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support.

If $X$ is compact, then the measures in the dual space of $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ are finite because they are regular.